# How to hold my response in nodejs until the end of my loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

My code is as follows :

```
myinsts.forEach(function (myinstId) {
Organization.getOrgById(myinstId,function (err,insts)
{
   res.json(insts);
})
});
```

I'm usng Node.js and I'm getting the error "Can't set headers after they are sent" , Obviously my server sends first iteration , how can I make it hold until I get the whole data

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this type of question.  You can't "hold" a loop in Javascript for an async operation.  You have to do the iteration differently and process the results only when they are all done.  In addition, you have to specify what you want to do with N sets of results from your iteration.  You only get to send one response.

Comment: @jfriend00 this somehow got one upvote

Comment: For each organization id , I want to retrieve  a list of its employees, and  then send my data in this format :  {org1,org2} and {EmpsOrg1,EmpsOrg2}

Comment: Hi @YoussefKorchi if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to be pretty. Essentially what you could do is create a variable to hold the data through every iteration and then check if that's the last callback to be called. If it is, then you can output your json. Try something like the following:

```
var _counter = 0;
var _values = [];

myinsts.forEach(function (myinstId) {
Organization.getOrgById(myinstId,function (err,insts)
{
   _values.push(insts);
   if(++_counter == myinsts.length)
      res.json(_values);
})
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution , I've just one more question please, is there any other solution, I mean a better way to do that kind of asynchronous responses , I know I have to use callbacks but I still don't understand using them.

Comment: But this could be dangerous because the callback that fires res.json() could be the first or second executed and _values probably sometimes won't get all the "insts" values.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Huh? I don't understand what you're trying to say. res.json is only fired when the value of _counter is equal to the length of myinsts. And, that only happens after every insts value is pushed into the _values array.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that if getOrderById function is asynchronous, maybe doing a database call to fetch the data. You call that function foreach element in loop and the callbacks will be fired whenever in the future and maybe the last callback (which call res.json) could be finish after other callbacks, so you won't get all the data since its _values.push() won't be called.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo That will not happen. Remember, JavaScript has a single threaded stack, so if that getOrderById function is asynchronous the forEach will push each callback version of getOrderById into the callback queue. As a result they will each be evaluated individually, one by one. So, when each callback is evaluated _counter gets incremented. But that happens if and only if the entire callback is evaluated meaning that _values will have every possible value of insts.

Comment: I have done a fiddle to reproduce this behaviour : https://jsfiddle.net/jzee687c/ Basically what I want to say is that you don't have control of what callback will be executed first and what callback  will be executed last. It's randomly with your code and sometimes res.json() will be fired before some callbacks finish. Take a look to fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ntice that counter is increased after callback is called. My fault.

Comment: It's okay, it happens

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this kind of works, you can execute each async function in parallel with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and get the data in the order that is called.

```
var promises = [];
myinsts.forEach(function (myinstId) {
  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    Organization.getOrgById(myinstId,function (err,insts){
      if(err) return reject(err);
      resolve(insts);
    });
  }));
});
Promise.all(promises)
.then((allInsts)=>{res.json(allInsts)}) // all data fetched in loop order.
.catch((error)=>{console.log(error)});
```

Also consider to make your getOrgById handler return a Promise instead of using callback.

Comment: I think you could simplify this a bunch. `Promise.all(myinsts.map(Organization.getOrgById)).then(res.json).catch(res.status(500).json)`  Should do the trick.

Comment: You're right! Just to maintain the syntax of the question. :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to send response just one time, not several times. Your code send the response each of iteration. Send the response once if specific condition fulfilled. Like below.

```
myinsts.forEach(function (myinstId, index) {
    Organization.getOrgById(myinstId,function (err,insts){
       if( index == myinsts.length -1 ){
           res.json(insts);
       }
    })
});
```